# How can I use Google Picker to select a photo from a shared album?

Tags: picasa, google-picker

At the moment, my code to create the Picker is similar to:

```
 let builder = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
 .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
 .setDeveloperKey(apiKey)
 .setCallback(pickerCallback)
 .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_DRIVES)
...
 builder = builder
 .addView(google.picker.ViewId.PHOTOS)
 .addView(google.picker.ViewId.IMAGE_SEARCH)
 .addView(google.picker.ViewId.SPREADSHEETS)
 .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
 .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS_IMAGES)
 .addView(google.picker.ViewId.RECENTLY_PICKED);
...
 const picker = builder.build();
 picker.setVisible(true);
```

But only my own photos appear, and I do not see any of my shared albums, and so cannot select a photo from one of these shared albums.

E.g., when I select the "Your Photos" tab, I do not see any shared albums, only my own albums (see below).

[image]

And when I choose the "More" tab, there are no other options to select a photo from a shared album (see below).

[image]